# jQuery appendTo replaces elements instead of adding them, if elements being added pre-exist in the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<select id="name" >
    <option value="" selected="selected">Please select</option>
    <option value="Alex">Alex</option>
    <option value="Greg">Greg</option>
</select>
```

If we try to append an option to it, by

`$('<option>Hi</option>').appendTo($('#name'))`

then, the option is added to the select box, as is expected. But, if we do the following :

```
var a = $('#name option')[1];
$(a).appendTo($('#name'));
```

then, the option is not appended to the options. Instead, "Alex" now comes at the end. My question is that another "Alex" option should have been appended at the end, with the original "Alex" remaining in its place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#name option')[1]
```

**SELECTS** the element.

When you **SELECT** an element, you select it. lol..

It is not **COPIED**. To get the desired result you must do

```
var a = $('#name option')[1];
$(a).clone().appendTo($('#name'));
```

Comment: So, when we append an already existing option to the select box, the existing element moves out, and is inserted at the end ? Shouldn't there be some documentation on appending an already existing element ?

Comment: I don't know if this is worth mentioning in documentation or not. But the word `SELECT` pretty much has its own meaning :)
That is why these are `jQuery SELECTORS`. 
When you select something, you get a `pointer` to your DOM element. (Not exactly the memory address of the element lol).
If you've ever worked with `pointers`in `C` language, you will quickly understand this concept. :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
               $('#name').appendChid(option element);
```

or 
 try like this

```
            var container1 = document.getElementById('keylist');
            var new_element1 = document.createElement('OPTION');
            new_element1.text= m1[h1];
            container1.insertBefore(new_element1, container1.lastChild);
```